# Join lines after to text pattern in Vim

Tags: vim, regex

I'm trying without success to join lines using a vim

let say I've a text file which looks like this:

```
HI
Hello 
A, b, c, d,
HI
Hello 
A, b, c, d,
HI
Hello 
A, b, c, d,
HI
Hello 
A, b, c, d,
```

I want to join all lines that start with HI. to after of Hello. so that it looks like:

```
Hello HI
A, b, c, d,
Hello HI
A, b, c, d,
Hello HI
A, b, c,
Hello HI
A, b, c, d,
```

Comment: Can there be any lines between `HI` and `Hello`, or will they always be consecutive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:g/^Hello/m-2|j
```

This is the command you want.

- **g** is for the global command
- **^Hello** is the regex
- **m-2** moves the current line to 2 lines above its current position; means swap current line with the above one
- **j** joins the current line and the line above, inserting a space between the two. Use j! for no space.
- **|** separates the 2 ex-commands